# Tor detection in network

Tags: tls, tor

After I read this [link](http://www.netresec.com/?month=2013-04&page=Blog&post=Detecting-TOR-Communication-in-Network-Traffic), I tried to understand how they manage detect Tor traffic

The most understandable source for me was [this paper](http://brage.bibsys.no/hig/bitstream/URN:NBN:no-bibsys_brage_17639/1/Identifying_TLS_abnormalities_in_Tor_AndersOlausGranerud.pdf)

He is saying Tor traffic can be detected by port, cipher suite length , extensions and validity duration of certificate can be use. I tried to implement that and I saw Tor corrected all their weaknesses which are pointed in the document.

According to my experiences it is not possible to detect Tor users in network, but how are companies able to detect Tor? I am extremely curious. Does Tor have any TLS abnormalities?

Comment: Our company uses what it calls 'Next Gen Firewalls' which do DPI and 'know' the signature of TOR traffic as well as maintaining a list of TOR end-points. As a result, i've never been able to get TOR traffic through it no matter what options i use.

Comment: @D3C4FF Even with [obfsproxy](https://www.torproject.org/projects/obfsproxy.html.en)?

Comment: @Adnan obfsproxy = bridges? Then yes. That gets blocked as well.

Comment: @D3C4FF do you have any idea have to get list f TOR end-points

Comment: @KadirErdemDemir what? I don't understand.

Comment: @D3C4FF Maybe I completely misunderstood you :), what I understand was there is a list of TOR nodes which is given by TOR itself(I can't find the link now but I heard Tor did something like that because preventing of bad usage .). I thought you get this "list" somehow. But when I read again for first message I see you made your own list with DPI.

Answer (score 8):

Blocking Tor at a network level is difficult, and anyone trying to do so will face a constant battle with the Tor developers. It's similar to the red queen effect between malware developers and AV researchers; every time an improved technique comes out to block Tor the developers will change the way it works.

I see Tor use as more of an endpoint control issue, and a user behavior issue rather than a network blocking issue. If you want to stop Tor then prevent it from being installed, and let users know the penalties for using it (providing you have an applicable AUP which says so).

Comment: othertopic....why blocking entry point IPs of Tor does not work?

Comment: You can't differentiate ToR traffic from regular web traffic @again.

Comment: but in packet there is destination ip of entry node. Is possible to collect all entry node IPs?

Comment: No, they change often and there's no definitive list @again.